R3F Decal with specific shapes
I want to be able to change the shape of Decal mesh such that the image appears cropped according to the given shape. My attempt was to make it a triangle.
const Image = ({ position, image, scale, setIsHoveredG }) => {
    const [imageTexture] = useState(() => {
        const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image)
        texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
        texture.repeat.x = -1
        texture.offset.x = 1
        return texture
    }) //To flip image left right

    const ref = useRef();
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

    scale = isHovered ? scale.map(value => value * 1.15) : scale;

    return (
        <Decal
            position={position}
            scale={scale}
            onPointerEnter={(event) => { setIsHovered(true); setIsHoveredG(true); }}
            onPointerLeave={() => { setIsHovered(false); setIsHoveredG(false); }}
            onClick={() => { store.image = image; }}
        >
            <meshBasicMaterial
                map={imageTexture}
                polygonOffset
                polygonOffsetFactor={isHovered ? -2 : -1}
            />
        </Decal>
    );
};

I tried adding mesh geometries but nothing worked. Please help. This is my first time working with r3f/threejs because I need it for a university project.

I was playing with this while… Problem was, that you don’t have primitive triangle, plane is easy. I was trying Cone, Octahedron and Shape. Probably you can tweaking these geometry to achieve desired result, but is tedious. I created basic triangle programmatically, thing is with this solution, that you will have to adjust this triangle to your mesh, and that can be tedious as well… a lot of tweaking… Because you will have to achieve perfect relation between position, rotation and scale accordingly to shape of your model. I was wondering why don’t you use normal image to create this triangle like in official r3f documentation, well, maybe you had reason of that.
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { OrbitControls, Decal } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three'

function Box(props) {
  const ref = useRef()
  useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.rotation.x += delta))

const triangleShape = new THREE.Shape()
  triangleShape.moveTo(0, 1)
  triangleShape.lineTo(-1, -1)
  triangleShape.lineTo(1, -1)
  triangleShape.lineTo(0, 1)
  const triangleGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(triangleShape)

  return (
    <mesh
  {...props}
  ref={ref}
>
  <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
  <meshStandardMaterial color='orange' />

<Decal
      triangleGeometry
      position={[0, 0.3, 0.3]}
      rotation={[0.8, 0.8, 0]}
      scale={[0.7, 0.7, 0.7]}
    >
        <meshBasicMaterial
          color='blue'
          side={THREE.DoubleSide}
          polygonOffset
          polygonOffsetFactor={-1}
        />
    </Decal>
</mesh>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={2} />
      <Box position={[0, 0, 0]} />
      <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

UPDATE
So, as I wrote above, the issue is not problematic when it comes to the primitive shape of the decal, because R3F is based on vanilla Three.js. If you take a look at the DecalGeometry constructor you will see that it can be any mesh.
    DecalGeometry( mesh : Mesh, position : Vector3, orientation : Euler, size : Vector3 )

mesh — Any mesh object.

I wanted to know how to change decal shape as I also wanted to create
a plain mesh also without any image.

My example is based on the mesh per se without mapping. You can of course use an image on this mesh, because now there is only color.
The essence of your question, I think, is modifying geometry, which is easy with the native geometries that Three provides. And it's a bit more difficult when you have to create such a shape programmatically. That's what I did in the example I gave.
All what you need is here, you can create any shape, but like I mentioned, programmatically.
const triangleShape = new THREE.Shape()
  triangleShape.moveTo(0, 1)
  triangleShape.lineTo(-1, -1)
  triangleShape.lineTo(1, -1)
  triangleShape.lineTo(0, 1)
  const triangleGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(

Look at these as well, that should help to understand.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes

Hey thank you for the response.
I wanted to know how to change decal shape as I also wanted to create a plain mesh also without any image.
But I will try what you did and also check how to do it with normal image. Thank you so much!

@ChamudPathirana I updated me original answer, take a look, please.
